# How to show the web content in our android app without using browser

Tags: android

Here i am developing an android app as well as web page. I need to show the web content in my android activity without using browser.

I am using `WebView` for this requirement. But the problem is if i click the button it opens in browser.

Here i have to display that page in my android app as new activity.

This is the code i have tried for this issue.

webview.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_tab_host_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

this is my Admissionactivity which need to show the web content

```
    public class AdmissionActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView webView;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_tab_host_webview);
             webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
}
```

this is the code for the button click

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_college_listview);
        intro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro_button);
        intro.setText("Introduction");
        intro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent admAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdmissionActivity.class);
                // Clears History of Activity
                admAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(admAct);


            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just implement the web client and set it before loadUrl. The simplest way is:**

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: thanks for the response i will check it and inform to you

Answer (score 0):

```
    //prevent web browser launch with loading http url
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
```